# Is this possible to hit single api multiple time in cypress js

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

For Example, I have api "localhost:4000/api/register" i want to hit this api 10 times in single test case

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash method `Cypress._.times()`

Example:

```
Cypress._.times(10, (k) => {
  it(`register ${k + 1} times`, () => {
    // here the test
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can like this also,
This is sample one which I used,

```
const count = 10;
static pollAndWait(count) {
        
        cy.testNetwork().then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);

            if (response.body.resultSizeEstimate > 0  || count == 0) {
                return;
            }
            else {
               this.testNetwork(--count);
            }
        });
    }
```